# RadGrid Default Selection first row

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, telerik-grid

I am using RAD Grid View and i want to select the first row default so i have added property
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = True
After that the default selection of first row style is different 
if i select it manually the style is different and default selected style is different can any one can help me on this

Comment: Probably because currentItem has a different style than selectedItem. And your selected item may not be 'Selected'. Only the current item.

Answer (score 0):

Im using SelectedItem=Model in XAML. Then simply set the Property 'Model' to the First item of the List of the Grid View:

```
 <telerik:RadGridView Name="DataGrid"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  IsFilteringAllowed="True"                                                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List}"                                           
 SelectedItem="{Binding  Path=Model}" >

    public xxx Model
    {
        get
        {
            return _model;
        }

        set
        {


            _model = value;

OnPropertyChanged(() => Model);
        }
```

Now set `Model = List.First();`and it should be selected.